# How to get current stock of a product using stock_quant and sql query by date in odoo?

Tags: odoo

I can get current stock of a product in a warehouse in current time using stock_quant table and sql query.

But how is it possible to get the current stock in a specific date using stock_quant table and sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get the stock of a product at a specific date using the `stock.quant` table. If you need to get the stock of a product at a certain date, you can try using the `qty_available` field in `product.product` model. You can pass to_date as context while fetching the `qty_available` field which will get you the stock at a specific date.